# AWS Cloudformation: is there a way to capture Glue ARN for use in a step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

My task is to create a cloudformation template that produces a glue job and then sets that glue job up as the first step function task.

I have the two pieces working separately, but I don't seem to be able to get the Glue job ARN, if there even is one created:

https://theburningmonk.com/cloudformation-ref-and-getatt-cheatsheet/

If it is created, according to this cheatsheet, it's not available to cloudformation GetAtt ..

Am I missing something? Any way to do this?

Comment: The Glue API doesn't return the ARN for any of its resources.  It's definitely a hole in their API, especially when you need the ARN to do other things like get the tags.

Comment: The format for Glue ARNs is defined here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-specifying-resource-arns.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[AWS::Glue::Job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-job.html#aws-resource-glue-job-return-values) **does not return its ARN**.

However, you can **construct it yourself**, since Glue job ARN has [known format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-specifying-resource-arns.html) and `!Ref <glue-job-resource>` returns job name.

So for example to return Arn in `Outputs`, you could do the following:

```
Outputs:
  JobArn:
    Value: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:glue:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:job/${<glue-job-resource>}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `boto3` then you need arns of glue.

here is the pattern. `Name` of job you can find by
`response = client.list_jobs(MaxResults=123)`

use a for loop to generate arns

```
for jb response['jobs']:
     arn:aws:glue:eu-central-1:1234567891011:job/jb
```

`"arn:aws:glue:<<region>>:<<accountid>>:job/<<NameOfJob>>"`

example output :

`"arn:aws:glue:eu-central-1:1234567891011:job/abc_s3_to_redshift"`